# Extract centroids of connected components in EMGU

Tags: emgucv

I have the following piece of code in EMGU to extract connected components:
Mat connected_array = new Mat();

```
            Mat stats = new Mat();
            Mat centroids = new Mat();
            Mat ImgMat = new Mat();
          CvInvoke.ConnectedComponentsWithStats(ImgThresh, connected_array, stats, centroids, LineType.EightConnected,DepthType.Cv32S);
```

I could not find any way to access the centroids.

Answer (score 3):

EMGU wraps most arrays into Mat objects, which you then need to convert to arrays to access their contents (using mat.CopyTo(array)). This is not straight forward from the documentation - I've had to use trail & error to find out how it works:

```
Mat labels = new Mat();
Mat stats = new Mat();
Mat centroids = new Mat();
MCvPoint2D64f[] centroidPoints;
double x, y;
int n;

n = CvInvoke.ConnectedComponentsWithStats(image, labels, stats, centroids, LineType.EightConnected, DepthType.Cv32S);

centroidPoints = new MCvPoint2D64f[n];
centroids.CopyTo(centroidPoints);

foreach (MCvPoint2D64f point in centroidPoints)
{
    x = point.X;
    y = point.Y;
}
```

Another common method is to use Contours, similar functionality which EMGU also provides. I have used this for better performance. I include an example as well:

```
VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();
MCvMoments moments;
double area;
MCvPoint2D64f center;
int n;

CvInvoke.FindContours(image, contours, null, RetrType.External, ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);
n = contours.Size;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    area = CvInvoke.ContourArea(contours[i], false);
    moments = CvInvoke.Moments(contours[i]);
    center = moments.GravityCenter;
}
```